# why C++ STL have five different iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

### why C++ STL have five iterators? Only random iterator could be sufficient to operate on all the containers. Any specific reason?

Sorry..It is my mistake..I did't mean random iterator...I was supposed to ask about bidirectional iterator...So don't you think that only bidirectional iterator can cover the functionality of input, output, forward iterators? So is there any specific reason to introduce (input, output, forward) iterators concept? Thanks. –

Comment: How do you operate a random-access iterator over a [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list), much less a [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)?

Comment: 10.000 answers to this. Not every collection can be accessed (note each word) in both direction (maps, graphs, single linked lists) and in constant time.

Comment: `Only random iterator could be sufficient to operate on all the containers.` Nope, wrong. Funny how the C++ standard body knows better than you do, as it turns out ;)

Answer (score 6):

Containers aren't the the only interesting sequence. Also, `std::list<...>` and the associative containers don't have an efficient method for random access although they are containers. `std::forward_list<...>` can walk in just one direction. When sequences are sources or drains, they can often just traversed once. Oh, look! I actually gave reasons for all five categories!

Note that the "STL iterators" are not classes but *concepts*, i.e., requirements for operations and associated types needed to meet the respective iterator concept. The basic idea is that algorithm interfaces are specified in terms of the weakest concepts yielding an efficient implementation. When stronger concepts are provided to the algorithms they may be able to apply some optimizations. This approach yields flexible and efficient algorithms operating on all kinds of different sequences.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea why [check this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)

A random access iterator cannot always work. A simple example: If you're streaming data via the network, you cannot start again from the beginning. There are more reasons, but simply read the page.